# riemann intergration problem

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

hi could anyone help me with the following problem?

[image]

Mainly because i have don't know the method, I know we need to know the upper and lower sums but i don't know how to apply them

Comment: Do you know continuous functions are integrable? If so, show $h$ is continuous.  On the other hand, $h'$ can be written as $h' = u + v,$ where $u$ is continuous and $v$ is continuous, since continuous functions are integrable and difference of integrable functions is integrable, conclude that if $h'$ _were_ integrable, $v$ would be integrable. To show that $v$ is not integrable is quite easy, since you can create a partition of $[0, 1]$ and two valid choices of tags there for which one choice will give the positive harmonic series and the other choice the negative (or of that ordre).

Comment: Yeah i know that continuous functions are integrable but is that the same as being riemann integrable?

Comment: No. The function $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in ]1, 2]$ is integrable and not continuous.

Comment: but for riemann integration the fact holds or am i misunderstanding ?

Comment: Being continuous is **not** the same as being Riemann integrable. _Lebesgue's criterion_ for Riemann integration asserts that every Riemann integrable function is not necessarily continuous but not too discontinuous (the set of discontinuities is of measure zero)

Comment: What do mean by "integrable" if not "Riemann integrable"